Пересылка сообщение с помощью бота
подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает данный способ?
Обозначил кнопку
[InlineKeyboardButton("Уведомление", callback_data='notification')],

дальше
elif query.data == 'notification':
    await query.edit_message_text("Введите сообщение")
    return "AWAITING_NOTE"

дальше
"AWAITING_NOTE": [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, send_message_f)],

и функция
async def send_message_f(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
note_text = update.message.text
context.user_data['note_text'] = note_text

await update.message.reply_text("Ваше замечание принято. Оно будет отправлено")
target_chat_id = "хххххх" 
await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=target_chat_id, text=f"Новое замечание:\n{note_text}")
return ConversationHandler.END

